# After defining a function how do I solve for one of the arguments?

Tags: python, function

I am very new to programming. I wrote my very first code on 8/14/20,so I am less than a month into learning. I say this so that you have patience if my code isn't "pretty." I don't know what I don't know. I have built a function that is a BMI calculator. After it calculates the BMI it thens displays the BMI number and a message. If someone is considered overweight I want it to also solve for 'lbs' variable in bmi_calc. For the example below my goal is to change the string that is returned in the first if statement to say, 'You need to lose X lbs to achieve the ideal BMI.' lbs is what I want to solve for.I've tried to Google, but I am finding it hard to research because I do not know how to succinctly describe what I want to create. I am using Python 3.8. Any help is appreciated.

```
def bmi_calc(inches, lbs):
    kg=lbs*.453592
    meters=inches*.0254
    bmi=kg/meters**2
    round_bmi=round(bmi,2)
    if round_bmi>=30.0:
        return'Your BMI is'+' '+str(round_bmi)+'.'+' '+'This means you are obese. Consider a weight loss strategy.'
    elif 29.90 <=round_bmi >=25.0:
        return('Overweight')
    elif 24.9 <=round_bmi >=18.5:
        return('Healthy Weight')
    elif round_bmi<18.5:
        return('underweight')

print(bmi_calc(70,260))
```

Comment: I know the math, but should I incorporate it in the if statement?

Comment: What do you mean solve for it?  You don't need to solve anything, you already have the value of lbs in the variable lbs.  You use it in the very first line of the function.  If your question is instead how to solve for the lbs given a bmi and a height in inches, well forget code for a minute, just write that out on paper.  It's basic algebra.  Then code that formula/

Comment: the actual formulation is simple algebra - solve for lbs for a given BMI+inches. it is your choice where you put that into your code.. if you want a msg to display "overweight - get down to X lbs" then yes it should be in the if statement

Comment: I figured it out everyone. Thank you for your assistance. I was overthinking this. All I had to do was like everyone said write out the actual math and then program it in the function assigned to a variable. I then included that variable in my string.

Comment: Your left side comparators are incorrect on the bounds checks.  You have <= and they should be >= for this pythonic form:  `if  upper >= x >= lower:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is more of a math problem than programming you can just plug the algebraic formula into your code in this manner-

```
def bmi_calc(inches, lbs):
    ideal_bmi = 21.7
    kg=lbs*.453592
    meters=inches*.0254
    bmi=kg/meters**2
    round_bmi=round(bmi,2)

    ideal_weight = (ideal_bmi * (meters**2))/0.453592

    if round_bmi>=30.0:
        return'Your BMI is'+' '+str(round_bmi)+'.'+' '+'This means you are obese. you need to lose ' + str(lbs - ideal_weight) + ' lbs to reach the ideal weight'
    elif 29.90 >=round_bmi >=25.0:
        return('Overweight')
    elif 24.9 >=round_bmi >=18.5:
        return('Healthy Weight')
    elif round_bmi<18.5:
        return('underweight')

print(bmi_calc(70,260))
```

Comment: Your left side comparators are incorrect on the bounds checks.  You have <= and they should be >= for this pythonic form:  `if  upper >= x >= lower:`

Comment: @RufusVS I just copied what the question asker had in their code and added the requested lines, but you are correct they comparators are incorrect and I will edit the answer to use the proper ones